# Setting color info without defining new instance of renderer

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have an esri map with five feature layers. Each also has an id, and it is used in a toggle layer function to update layer visibility in the map. For most layers, I just need to set one static color for all features. I do so as follows:

```
var normalLayer = new FeatureLayer(url,{stuff});
normalLayer.on('load',function(){
  normalLayer.renderer.setColorInfo({
    field: 'field',
    colors: ['#ffffff']
  });
  normalLayer.renderer.setOpacityInfo({
    opacityValues: [0.50]
  });
});
```

For two of the five layers, I'm trying to set a color ramp. I'm using [these](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/renderer.html#setcolorinfo) instructions. Here is my code:

```
var colorRampLayer = new FeatureLayer(url,{stuff});
colorRampLayer.on('load',function(){
  colorRampLayer.renderer.setColorInfo({
    field: 'field',
    colors: ['#ffffff','#002a5c'],
    minDataValue: 0,
    maxDataValue: 15.51
  });
  colorRampLayer.renderer.setOpacityInfo({
    opacityValues: [0.50]
  });
});
```

What I'm expecting is for a color ramp to be generated  for this feature layer, starting at white (#ffffff) and ending at dark blue (#002a5c). But what happens is everything comes in as the same color. I also tried defining stops per the API reference linked above. These however don't seem to allow for a range of values to be represented by stops. For example if I define the stops as 1,2,3,4,5 only polygons with exactly the values 1,2,3,4,5 get colors and everything else is blank.

Answer (score 1):

i'm fairly certain you just need to instantiate a new renderer and pass it through by calling [`FeatureLayer.setRenderer()`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/featurelayer-amd.html#setrenderer) instead.